# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, users, meta

We clearly need to do some promotion to get this site launched as Robert Cartaino has stated in [this thread](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/expressionengine-se-not-ready-for-public-launch). During the build up to public beta there were at least four blog posts on the importance of the EE stack Overflow proposal and dozens of tweets daily. I think we should continue to do this sort of activity.

Additionally we need to be more proactive about getting existing members to participate. An additional option is to invite other well known developers who may not be involved in the private beta yet.

It would probably be a good idea to get Ryan Irelan or Kyle Cotter to post another news item about EE SO over at EE Insider.

Any other ideas for promotion?

blog posts:

1. [Help Support The Stack Overflow ExpressionEngine Proposal](http://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/help-support-the-stack-overflow-expressionengine-proposal)
2. [Why Stack Exchange matters](https://exp-resso.com/blog/post/2012/10/why-stack-exchange-matters)
3. [Proposed ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange Site](http://www.mediagirl.com/blog/entry/proposed_expressionengine_stack_exchange_site/)
4. [Stack Exchange ExpressionEngine Site Proposa](http://eeinsider.com/blog/stack-exchange-expressionengine-site-proposal/)l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree we need to be better at keeping up the volume of the public awareness campaign we had prior to beta. I think there was a feeling after we got the beta that "oh good, we're going to get it, I can relax" (at least I felt this way). Now is more time than ever to push for it harder.

One tip I could say is that everyday we all (as in those who've committed to the project) spend 10-15 minutes out of our day to do something for the site. Promote it on twitter, send an invite, write an email to someone who can promote it out.

Answer (score 6):

Currently writing a piece for EE Insider on this. If you could offer 1 tip to make sure this site makes it to public launch, what would it be?

Comment: I check the site 3-4 times a day upvote if I don't know the answer and think it's a good question and answer where I can. I was holding back on asking questions as I didn't actually have any real questions and didn't want to keep asking questions I already know the answer to. Anyhow, my suggestion  is to keep checking in and post both questions and answers.