# Is there a minimum reputation requirement for asking questions?

Tags: support, reputation, asking-questions

At least two members of the private beta who'd like to participate mentioned getting a message:

> You must have at least 5 reputation on ExpressionEngine to ask a
>   question.

Is this indeed the case? Seeing as we're trying to promote the site and help committed members get active in the private beta, this would be a significant obstacle.

If there is such a limit, what is the simplest way for the user to gain enough reputation to ask a question?

Comment: Agree, this seems like a bit of a catch 22. People on twitter are complaining that they can't ask or even answer questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [looks to me](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22You%20must%20have%20at%20least%205%20reputation%22) as though the 5 rep minimum only applies to Meta, not the main site.

> Remember that the most basic functions (asking and answering) require
>   no reputation at all, so you can build up reputation simply by asking
>   and answering questions and reputation is awarded to you through the
>   community vote.
>   - [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139386)

I'm wondering whether a lot of the users having problems have not fully activated their accounts. There do seem to be a huge number of [zero rep](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users?page=8&tab=reputation&filter=month) users and I *think* a new user should have 1 rep by default (which grants quite a [lot of permissions](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) while in beta).

Comment: Yes, those users are almost certainly trying to post a question to the meta site. If anyone can reproduce this problem on the *main* site, please report it here.

Answer (score 3):

"Simplest" way is to get active on other SE sites, I think. But then you run into that annoying "link up your account" issue. That had me confused for a while...

Comment: Your rep on other SE sites is entirely separate, but you can get 100 rep for 'free' if you link your account to another SE account with > 200 rep.